Trouble initializing Branch. Failed to connect to api2.branch.io/0.0.0.0:443 Check network connectivity or DNS settings
On android devices the branch.io is not working due to an error saying:
Trouble initializing Branch. Failed to connect to api2.branch.io/0.0.0.0:443 Check network connectivity or DNS settings.
The error appers when doing:
branch.subscribe({onOpenComplete: ({params, error, uri}) => {console.log({error})}});
Followed the docs regarding the documantion and until this point nothing looks like can cause this error.
